# posting a variable with jquery and receiving it on other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I want to post a variable `id` to a page. I'm trying the following code, but I can't get the id value, it says `undefined`.

```
function box(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");

    $("#votebox").slideDown("slow");
    $("#flash").fadeIn("slow");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
  //I want to post the "id" to the rating page.
        data: "id="+$(this).attr("id"),
        url: "rating.php",
        success: function(html){
            $("#flash").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#content").html(html);
        } 
    });
}
```

This function is called in the following code. In the following code too, the id is posted to the page `votes.php`, and it works fine, but in the above code when I'm trying to post the id to the `rating.php` page, it does not send.

```
$(function(){
$("a.vote_up").click(function(){

the_id = $(this).attr('id');
$("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut("fast");
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "action=vote_up&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
        url: "votes.php",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeOut();
            $("span#votes_up"+the_id).html(msg);
            $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeIn();
            var that = this;
            box.call(that); 
        }
    });
});       
 });
```

rating.php

```
<?
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
?>
```

The html part is:

```
<a href='javascript:;' class='vote_up' id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Vote Up!</a>
```

I'll appriciate any help.

Comment: What are you trying to get the ID from?

Comment: Be careful that you get the id right. You have the variable id, so use that instead of reproducing the code for the data attribute. I have a feeling that the "this" keyword is not referencing what you think it is, and it is sending empty data.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added extra code where the function is called. Please note that when the id is posted in the other code, it works fine, but it does not work fine when i try to post in the box().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with what `this` is in the context of an AJAX event handler.  Your AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "action=vote_up&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
    url: "votes.php",
    success: function(msg)
    {
        $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeOut();
        $("span#votes_up"+the_id).html(msg);
        $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeIn();
        var that = this;
        box.call(that); 
    }
});
```

In the `success` handler, `this` is not the the element in the event handler.  Instead it is the `XMLHTTPRequest` object from the AJAX request.  You need to cache `that` outside the event handler:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "action=vote_up&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
    url: "votes.php",
    success: function(msg)
    {
        $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeOut();
        $("span#votes_up"+the_id).html(msg);
        $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeIn();
        box.call(that); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you see, I post ID in function.. it works fine (I can get it on votes.php), however when i call the box() within this code, and I try to post the same ID in the box() to the rating.php, I can not get the ID there. I tried with your answer but it still does not work. I'll appreciate if you can have a look again at my original post.

Comment: @Billa I don't quite understand what you're saying.  This is, I think, the code that should go in your event handler `$("a.vote_up").click(function(){ /*code*/ });` In what way doesn't it work? What error do you get?

Comment: Oh. It just works fine, I actually forgot to remove that variable inside the event handler, that's why it did not work. Now it works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, no worries then -- glad it's sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not installed [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) then I think you should do that first.

Next I would output id to console:

```
var id=$(this).attr("id");
console.log(id);
```

There could be a good chance that id is not what you thought it was. If correct then you could continue reading on.

**From the jquery documentation**

> Example: Alert out the results from
>   requesting test.php with an additional
>   payload of data (HTML or XML,
>   depending on what was returned).

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

This might work:

```
$.post("rating.php", { id: id }, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: `this.id` is safe... no need for jQuery there.

Comment: I did not say it was unsafe, but it could contain another value you wanted it to have(maybe undefined or something).